# Can anyone give me a working example of expandable recycler view.?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am new at Android development and I need to implement a recycler view that can expand but when I searched on google, I get nothing. There are two or three libraries which are present on github for this purpose but neither of which I understand. So, after two days of searching on expandable recycler view, output is null. ANy help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**I think you might Looking for this.**

**Follow below Link.**

https://github.com/mrzulkarnine/RecyclerView-With-Expandable-Item-Demo

Do `Modification` as you required in your `Recycler View` items.

**EDIT 1**

**Follow this link.**

https://github.com/bignerdranch/expandable-recycler-view

Hope it will gives what you want.

Comment: I want to handle the click events on subitems, and using this I am not be able to handle click events on subitems

Comment: @AnkitArora Might be you need to do some modification as what you need in code for that if you using that library. I have already mentioned in my answer.

Comment: @AnkitArora Check my edited answer. I have given another link might be it will help you to handle sub items click events.

Comment: I am not able to properly understand this. I spends many hours on this library

Comment: @AnkitArora Use first link which i have given do some modification. If you have tried any code then Post your code whatever you tried and say what issue you are facing.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42572880/2772552